# 403 ошибка при попытке скачать APK из Firebase App Distribution

Tags: android, firebase

прошу помощи.
Подключил Firebase к своему первому приложению, в App Distribution добавил список тестировщиков, но при попытке тестировщиков перейти по ссылке и скачать apk или приложение app tester вылезает ошибка 403.

[image: 403 ошибка]

Не могу понять какие права необходимо предоставить? Справка Firebase ссылается на Google Workspace

[image: Справка Firebase]

Как устранить ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с этой же проблемой. Видел пост о том, что Google ограничила доступ к скачиванию сборок некоторым странам и регионам. Не знаю откуда вы, но я из России, и она под эти ограничения в связи с политической ситуацией попала. Возможно у вас ситуация схожая

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Да, я тоже из России. Спасибо за комментарий!

Comment: Скиньте ссылку на пост, было бы интересно почитать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте зайти под американским VPN перед тем, как скачивать сборки с Firebase App Distribution. Я попробовал сегодня, у меня получилось (благодарность [пользователю evsxez1](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661432) c developer.apple.com).